# SQL: Collapsing Rows into Sum [Performance]

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

First off, I have a perfectly working solution to my problem, it just isn't fast enough.

My data is for hourly time cards, for a week at a time.

```
create table WeeklyHours
(
    Id int identity(1,1) not null,
    ResourceID int not null,
    WeekOf datetime not null,
    Sunday decimal(8, 5) not null,
    Monday decimal(8, 5) not null,
    Tuesday decimal(8, 5) not null,
    Wednesday decimal(8, 5) not null,
    Thursday decimal(8, 5) not null,
    Friday decimal(8, 5) not null,
    Saturday decimal(8, 5) not null,
    Total decimal(8, 5) not null,
    BufferFor int null,
)
```

What our system allows, is that if a person is sick, another person can fill in for them. This is called Buffering. The BufferFor field will be a ResourceID of the person who is being covered for, or NULL if they are regular work hours.

What I want to do is collapse the buffered rows INTO the regular work hours. (We grantee there will be a regular work hours row, even if it is all 0s)

Here is how I did it (the table is filtered down by applicable rows in a date range):

```
select 
    WH.ResourceID, 
    WeekOf, 
    Monday + ISNULL((select SUM(Monday) from WeeklyHours WH2 where WH2.BufferFor = WH.ResourceID and WH2.WeekOf = WH.WeekOf),0) as M, 
    Tuesday + ISNULL((select SUM(Tuesday) from WeeklyHours WH2 where WH2.BufferFor = WH.ResourceID and WH2.WeekOf = WH.WeekOf),0) as T, 
    Wednesday + ISNULL((select SUM(Wednesday) from WeeklyHours WH2 where WH2.BufferFor = WH.ResourceID and WH2.WeekOf = WH.WeekOf),0) as W, 
    Thursday + ISNULL((select SUM(Thursday) from WeeklyHours WH2 where WH2.BufferFor = WH.ResourceID and WH2.WeekOf = WH.WeekOf),0) as R, 
    Friday + ISNULL((select SUM(Friday) from WeeklyHours WH2 where WH2.BufferFor = WH.ResourceID and WH2.WeekOf = WH.WeekOf),0) as F, 
    Saturday + ISNULL((select SUM(Saturday) from WeeklyHours WH2 where WH2.BufferFor = WH.ResourceID and WH2.WeekOf = WH.WeekOf),0) as S, 
    Sunday + ISNULL((select SUM(Sunday) from WeeklyHours WH2 where WH2.BufferFor = WH.ResourceID and WH2.WeekOf = WH.WeekOf),0) as U,
from
    WeeklyHours WH
where 
    WH.WeekOf >= @applicableMonday
    and WH.WeekOf <= @lastDay
```

I have a clustered primary key on Id.

I have a non-clustered index on `ResourceID,WeekOf` that also has the `Mon-Sun` hours and `BufferFor` for the subselects.

The perf on this is okay, not terrible, but not very good either. The total cost to run my Func is about .2019 seconds. This query is about 65% of the total cost of my Func and returns only ~5500 rows (after I filter out the buffer rows). But since this ends up getting called ~2000 times from another proc, it ends up costing me ~7 min.

Is there a faster way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]`

Comment: The index in the question on `ResourceID,WeekOf` is not clustered, should it be?

Comment: Perhaps you can find a way not to call this 2000 times.  That seems like the performance killer.

Comment: I agree, my func was designed to calculate the cost between two dates for either a single resource, or all resources on a single project. Which is why it gets called 12*Number of Projects (ie. once per fiscal month per project) for one of the views.

Answer (score 3):

Your performance is pretty good. Your problem is that you're being abused by, what sounds like poor coding, in the sproc you mentioned. So, let's say you manage to improve the performance of your query by 90% and soon after the sproc starts calling your query 20,000 times... you're back where you started.

I would begin by investigating the problem sproc to see if there's a better solution than thousands of calls in a short period of time. Could be a simple fix of not calling a query from a loop, as a simple example. The client code could also use caching instead of calling a query repeatedly for data that doesn't change much.

If you want to follow the performance route then I would suggest denormalizing. Since your query results are boxed by week, denormalizing is actually a good solution. You would create another table and populate it with results from your query... You would also not be calling tour subqueries all the time. SQL Server usually optimizes for that but it's definitely something worth trying.

Good luck.

Comment: so unpivot and get something more like this for column info: `ResourceID, Date, Hours, BufferFor` and then do a collapse somehow?
Also the other sproc is garanteed to call me a fairly fixed amount of times. It is once per month per project. We currently have about 165 projects and don't expect to grow significantly. At most 2x. (famous last words... lol)

Comment: Not exactly unpivot. Your denormalized table would actually look similar to your original, as you show it, but add a WeekId column to create week "buckets". You would also do all your ISNULL logic ahead of time.

Comment: Are you saying add `WeekID` and remove `WeekOf`, then have another table for the actual date? `WeekID, WeekOf`? In general there will still only be 1 pair of `WeekID,ResourceID`. Could I use a CTE to select out the buffer rows? Seems like it might work.

Comment: @ohmusama: Sorry, I'm starting to lose track of the OP. But in a nutshell you need to create a table that has no cruft of any kind which, when queried, does not need joins, no calculations, no null checks etc. The query against this table should just specify the week by whatever method you choose to track the week buckets. Using CTEs is fine but how you get that clean data is less important than the final data.